# Use of semaphores in C?

Tags: c++, c, semaphore

For example I have a machinist(x) process, where x can represent various tools a machinist has. There are three types of machinists, one with the screwdriver, another with a hammer, another with a brush.

All three tools are needed to manufacture a product. The robot process takes one of the tools,  and takes the two other tools from the machinists that have them to complete a product. This process iterates over and over again indefinitely (where the robot potentially takes a different starting tool every time).

I need to write a process manager using semaphores, REALLY confused :/

Basically I need pseudocode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have multiple robots, each in its own thread building a product?

Maybe something like this:  Each robot waits for and reserves the screwdriver, then does the same for the hammer etc.  After building the product release all tools.  One important consideration is reserve the tools in a consistent order; otherwise you risk deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, semaphore is a synchronization mechanism, to help synchronize shared object(s) Between multiple process/threads. Also remember, as semaphore is process specific, if one thread locks it another can unlock it. Now based on the above concept, if you can properly define your resources, and how processes/threads are going to acquire (i mean, can do some work with just one tool, or they need more then one) to get a piece of independent job done... etc, it will be easy for you and us to help each other.